# Xcode 4.4.1, iOS 5.1: Xcode cannot run using the selected device

Tags: ios

Need to to test my app on iphone 4 IOS 5.1.1. The provisioning profiles are ok. I get

"Cannot run using the selected device. No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. Connect an iOS device with a recent enough version or..."

Comment: Try closing Xcode, disconnect the device, reconnect the device, reopen Xcode. Sometimes Xcode gets messed up detecting the profiles on the device. If that doesn't work open the Organizer, cmd+shift+2, and see what the status of the device says.

Comment: Have you ever used this device for testing before with this version of Xcode?

Comment: Are you sure both ends of your cable are attached to the appropriate devices?

Comment: @Kevin is correct. your device is not connected to Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be iOS Version problem , I also encountered same problem Before and what i done is Just changed my Deployment target to Device OS version. To make This Use following Method.

Go to `Target-->Summary-->Deployment Target -->Select the Version.`
and  `Project-->info-->iOS Deployment target -->Select your Version.`