# Xcode cannot run using the selected device xcode 4.41 IOS 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode 4.4.1, iOS 5.1: Xcode cannot run using the selected device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13853286/xcode-4-4-1-ios-5-1-xcode-cannot-run-using-the-selected-device)

My xcode version is 4.4.1 and my iOS 5.1 .I intalled valid provisioned profile and certificates also. 
  when i  deploy xcode through device it shows error Xcode cannot run using the selected device No provisioned iOS devices are available with a compatible iOS version. If anyone know 
can you solve my problem?

Comment: Did you update your device?

Comment: Yes, I already updated again it shows same error

Comment: What is the iOS version of your device and what is the iOS version in your build settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you need to look into:

1. Is your device included in the provisioning profile?
2. Is the provisioning profile installed on the device?
3. What OS are you compiling for? Maybe your Deployment target is set to 6.0 while your device is 5.1. Your device needs to be at least the same version or higher than your deployment target.